# style.top inconsistent between JS, inline CSS, and getBoundingClientRect

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

Can someone shed a tiny bit of light on what is happening here?

[image: JS, inline CSS, and getBoundingClientRect]

Looking at the console I see three apparently incompatible numbers: on the same element temp0 (the highlighted one in the console, location pointed by the arrow, it's an asterisk), if I check `style.top` I get a value, inspecting the *inline CSS* a second one, and through `getBoundingClientRect.top` a third. What am I missing, or what could be the cause of something like this?

The structure of the `html` from top to bottom is: a couple of navbars, a `div` that takes up 30% of the `viewport height`, a second `div` that uses the remaining ~70%, organized in three columns through `bootstrap 4.5` (size 1-10-1).

The background is: I lost count of how many questions and articles have been reading trying to solve what looks like a silly alignment bug that keeps popping out in my code.

Tonight I thought I had found something definitive in [this function](https://javascript.info/coordinates#kx7yp3asgq) and detailed article, yet another two hours disappeared to no avail. When I saw the results of these three commands in the console I realized I needed help :P I would really appreciate any hint on what I am missing.

Comment: I see only two different values, `245px` and `545.75`, what's the third one?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect `Properties other than width and height are relative to the top-left of the viewport.`

Comment: You've identified the different APIs/props return different results, but what are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @Kaiido it was my attempt, seconds earlier, to set that same property at 320.75px.

Comment: @ksav yes, I'd say that had become (hopefully finally) clear last night after reading the article linked in the description.

Comment: But you never "got" that value back. That simply implies that an other script is running and setting that property. Then the two others are mostly unrelated, or at least they don't relate to the same thing at all.

Comment: @Kaiido hold on, I lost you: yes, there could be some script updating that property. I identified one, but its effect is clearly visible (it takes enough time to see the update in the DOM). From the comment/s above by now I understand that the inline might still be outdated/overpowered by some other setting, yet I am still missing 1) how my update of the property does not have *any* effect at all, not even for a split second, while I can see the other script's effect, and 2) why there would be no trace in the inline if the property has been updated by a script.

Comment: "I understand that the inline might still be outdated/overpowered by some other setting" the attribute would not, nor the "Element" section of the CSS panel, it could be stroked out, but that does show the value currently set as inline, even if it's not the one applied. So yes, the only explanation is that some other script did set the inline style in between. To check what did that you can right click the element in the tree view, and tick *Break on* > *attribute modifications*

Comment: Thanks @Kaiido, that trick of debugging the change of attribute helped. The culprit was still the script I had identified in my earlier debugging sessions, but I learned a cool debugging trick. The underlying problem now simply seems that either getBoundingRect().top gives me the wrong position for the element I am trying to align to (one of the paragraphs displayed in the document) or style.top sets it wrongon the asterisk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution was (ehm) simple:

> Now how does the position absolute work? The element is removed from the normal document flow, and no space is created for the element in the page layout. It is positioned *relative to its closest **positioned ancestor***, if any; otherwise, it is placed relative to the initial containing block. Its final position is determined by the values of top, right, bottom, and left. (from Mozilla WDN)

(bold & italic mine)

So as far as I understand: Because *the container* had `position: absolute;` the child was positioned relative *to the container* rather than the document itself. So no matter how hard I was trying, the `top` information of the two elements was never in sync, nor setting `style.top` based on that information could work.

Sometimes I feel hopeless in the face of CSS's subtleties, but hey *maybe* I got this one right.

Thank you @skyline3000 and @Kaiido for your clues.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you else you have going on in your page, but it looks like you tried to set the element's `style.top` to `320.75px` and although the console prints it out it doesn't look like the inline style was actually affected.

`style.top` is the equivalent of the inline style (and *not* anything defined in CSS). See the example below. `style.top` may not accurately represent where an element actually is on-screen. The first inner element has the default `position: static` so even tough it has a `top` set both inline and CSS, neither affects the element, yet `style.top` still shows `100px`.

`getBoundingClientRect()` is always relative to the *window*. The first inner element is actually 8px from the top of the page, which `rect.top` shows. The second inner element has `position: absolute`, so it is being affected by `style.top` and it actually is 250px from the top of the page.

```js
console.log('inner1 rect.top: ' +inner1.getBoundingClientRect().top);
console.log('inner1 style.top: ' +inner1.style.top);
console.log('inner2 rect.top: ' +inner2.getBoundingClientRect().top);
console.log('inner2 style.top: ' +inner2.style.top);
```

```css
#outer {
  background: red;
  display: block;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
}

#inner1 {
  background: yellow;
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  top: 5px;
  width: 100px;
}

#inner2 {
  background: blue;
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  top: 5px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner1" style="top:100px;"></div>
    <div id="inner2" style="position:absolute; top:250px;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sigh. Thank you @skyline. I reproduced your example in my editor and while it improved my understanding I am still lacking enough of it to understand why I can't vertically align two elements inside the DOM. I am sorry, it seems to be a blind spot of mine :(
Why two elements both sharing a `position: absolute` attribute can't be aligned through `style.top` still escapes me. [window is at the top, so that should not be influencing the outcome]. Might it be related to `bootstrap`?